# Nix unable to build Haskell with packages

Tags: haskell, nix

When I try to run

```
nix-shell -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (p: [p.brick])"
```

I receive the following error

```
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/14r35fzyw3y7mqzdzifbm9sd0599b1cl-ghc-8.6.5-with-packages.drv
building '/nix/store/14r35fzyw3y7mqzdzifbm9sd0599b1cl-ghc-8.6.5-with-packages.drv'...
/nix/store/k7yalpjh53xra535xaip1pfq6q4jgsc0-stdenv-linux/setup: line 822: /build/env-vars: No such file or directory
unpacking sources
/nix/store/k7yalpjh53xra535xaip1pfq6q4jgsc0-stdenv-linux/setup: line 822: /build/env-vars: No such file or directory
variable $src or $srcs should point to the source
builder for '/nix/store/14r35fzyw3y7mqzdzifbm9sd0599b1cl-ghc-8.6.5-with-packages.drv' failed with exit code 1
```

Notice that this does not happen if I pass an empty list of packages, so `nix-shell` itself works.

I tried to reinstall `nix-env -i ghc` but the error persists

Comment: Does the file `/build/env-vars` exist?

Comment: where? in the folder where I launch the command? Shouldn't this command be completely independent from where I launch it?

Comment: No -- `/build/env-vars` should exist. You can check its existence by typing `ls /build/env-vars`

Comment: This looks like a bug where build instructions are executed as part of the shellHook or a bug where some derivation is broken. Could you post the full log and the versions of Nix and Nixpkgs?

Comment: Your command should work. I wrongly assumed it was wrong at first and came up with an alternative. It should be equivalent, but perhaps you could try `nix-shell --expr 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; mkShell { buildInputs = [ (haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (p: [p.brick])) ]; }'`

Comment: That command works for me. I looked through all my /nix/store/*stdenv-linux*/setup files and the only mentions of env-vars are in a dumpVars() shell fn. What you install in the nix-env should not/won't effect what you do in the nix-shell, anyway. I think something else is failing--it looks like it's in the "unpackPhase()" That's where that error message about "$src or $srcs" is.

Comment: @RobertHensing I'm vorking with nix 2.3 and nixpkgs-unstable. The other command you suggested produces the same error. I'll update the question with the full error in a second

Comment: @marcosh As the user owning the nix-store (root for multiple user installs), install `nix-info` and call it. Tells us the names listed in the channels, they usually contain part of the commit sha of nixpkgs git repo, what commit you are using. With this commit, we can try to reproduce that. Also, what you install with `nix-env` is separate from the environment used in `nix-shell`. Did you call `nix-shell` from inside another `nix-shell`?

Comment: @typetetris the output of `nix-info` is `system: "x86_64-linux", multi-user?: no, version: nix-env (Nix) 2.3, channels(marcosh): "nixpkgs-20.03pre192821.b425012fdf4", nixpkgs: /home/marcosh/.nix-defexpr/channels/nixpkgs`. I'm not calling `nix-shell` inside another `nix-shell`; just launching the command in my terminal

Comment: @marcosh This works for me, even with that special commit.

Comment: @marcosh This turns into a chat, let's talk in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203255/question-59073912